# Dynamically adding in my page url into a html social share link

Tags: php, html, css

I need to add in my page url in: `data-sumome-share-url="pageurlhere"`.

I'm currently using:`<?php echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>`

But it's not working? Full code as follows:

```
<div data-sumome-share="Facebook" data-sumome-share-url="<?php echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" data-sumome-share-text="Great article, check it out..." class="social-icons" id="facebook_icon"><img src="https://www.moneynest.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/facebook-white.png" height="20px" class="social-image-align" >share<span data-sumome-share-count="share"></span></div>
```

**Live demo**

I've set up a test page - [here](https://www.moneynest.co.uk/testing-social-icons/).
The text: 'share' on click should load either a facebook, twitter or linkedin share (depending on which of the three you click) with the php echoing in the current page url as the share link.

Apologies for my naivety I am very new to PHP.

Comment: Your code is correct, it works fine for me. Ex: I tried it on localhost/test.php and data-sumone-share was filled with http://localhost/test.php

Comment: *But it's not working?* -- you need to explain what is not working.  What do you get?  Also, what kind of file are you editing?  i.e. "Full code as follows" refers to what file?

Comment: Apologies - see: https://www.moneynest.co.uk/testing-social-icons/ you can see the text: 'share' on click this should load either a facebook, twitter or linkedin share (depending on which of the three you click) with the php echoing in the current page url as the share link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.

It was correct, the reason it wasn't working was due to the SumoMe plugin I had running (which was used to launch the social share).

I removed `data-sumome-share-url=""` as SumoMe would pull in the active URL so I didn't need the echo.

Sam